# What is wrong with the syntax in this assign statement?

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error, verilog, assign

What is wrong with the syntax in this?
I get an error when compiling saying:

> syntax error in continuous assignment

```
module CONTROLROM(in, out);

input wire [63:0]in;
output wire [6:0]out;

assign out = 0000000'b7;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

You are in a country where they write from right to left.

`7'b0000000`